# crypto.createDecipheriv error when generating iv

Tags: node.js, cryptography

I'm having a very weird error using crypto.createDecipheriv

When defining the following code:

```
var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', '3dc837d877144001c1291fdda417903d9130aeac', '1234567890123456');
```

and the request reach this line I get an error right away, crashing my application:

```
Error: Invalid key length
    at Error (native)
    at new Decipheriv (crypto.js:282:16)
    at Object.Decipheriv (crypto.js:279:12)
```

Does any body know what may be causing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your key length is too short. `aes-256-cbc` requires a 256-bit key, meaning 32 bytes. However the (hex) key you are supplying is only 20 bytes.

Also, you need to use `new Buffer('myhexkey', 'hex')` as the key argument in order for the hex bytes to be decoded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me to figure out that the key I was passing was of the wrong size.